# Pylons 1.0 and SQLAlchemy 0.6 - How do I Model?

Tags: python, model, sqlalchemy, pylons

I've been reading http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/starting-the-simplesite-tutorial.html and following along with their SimpleSite tutorial but am having some issues with creating the Model.

The Model imports they use on the tutorial are:

```
"""The application's model objects"""
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

from simplesite.model import meta

# Add these two imports:
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import schema, types
```

They then use this to create a table:

```
page_table = schema.Table('page', meta.metadata,
```

Though, when I try that, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'metadata'
```

I'm guessing Pylons changed their ways during the version upgrade...

So how do I do this? Can someone link me to an updated tutorial on making a Model and handling database connections/queries? :/

Comment: you can use `dir(meta)` to introspect the module - it's possible that metadata is renamed slightly

Answer (score 3):

Pylons 1.0 use declarative Base as default to model.

exemple:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Unicode,
from MYPROJECT.model.meta import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(Unicode(100))
```

You can see the updated reference in http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/models/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Base.metadata instead of meta.metadata for Pylons 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like that:

```
from blog.model.meta import Session, Base

article_table = sa.Table("article", Base.metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("lang", sa.types.String(255), nullable=False),
)
```